# Updating data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to update some data-attributes in my html.

I have something like this :

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li data-content="someContent"></li>
        <li data-content="someOtherContent"></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
 </div>

<div class="content" data-content="">
    <div class="whatever"></div>
    <input id="someID">
    <button>change TExt of div></button>
</div>
```

OK now when i click at one of the`<li>` the text which is stored in `data-content` is loaded in the `<div class="whatever>`.

Note that there is an `input`. This `input` changes the content of `<div class="whatever">`.When i change the text now,the `data-content`of `<li>` still contains the old text, but i want it to be the new text, that i have put in the input-field.

My Problem is now, that i cant select the `<li>` anymore, because i dont have a `$(this)`-Objet anymore that represents the current `<li>`.

Comment: What's your JS code?

Comment: for the button there is no JS-code since i dont know how i can select the respective <li>-Element.My other code has nothing to do with this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this http://jsbin.com/tesiduhozi/5/ ?
You can use .data() to store link for selected li

```
$(function() {
  $(document.body).on('click', 'li[data-content]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var content = $this.data('content');
    $('.whatever').html(content);
    $('#someID').val(content);
    $('.whatever').data('selectedLi', $this);
  });


  $(document.body).on('click', 'button', function() {
    var $li = $('.whatever').data('selectedLi');
    var content = $('#someID').val();
    if($li) {
      $li.data('content', content);
    }  

    $('.whatever').html(content);
  });
});
```

In this code when you get click on li[data-content] we update '.whatever' content and store link for selected li to data for .whatever element `$('.whatever').data('selectedLi', $this);`
.data() function allow to store any objects in associated with DOM element Hash-data object. On every new click will update this link

At any moment we can read this link from data with `$('.whatever').data('selectedLi')`. So on 'button' click we read this value. And if it's defined - it means that we save last clicked li element. So we can use it  ( we save jQuery element ) as jQuery element

For more details - ask or read documentation at https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: You're right. It's habitual to work with attributes for me - Can't believe that is the reason to decrease karma )

Comment: i think this will work, it is just hard to use this for my Project :P . I willl mark this as answer, when it worked.

Comment: @lolio Give more information. I tried to write code as I understand question. As you understand you should save link to current li to update it's data, so there are many places to store this information

Comment: exactly, can you add a little explanation on how i select the <li> inside your second piece of code?

Comment: maybe i am working too long on it, so i dont get it anymore, but this is exactly how it should work.I only dont understand it.